# Film development techniques.

Tags: discussion, faq-suggestion

Are film development techniques fair game or are they off-topic here. For instance, how should  [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1417/selenium-to-increase-contrast) be treated?

Although film development is a key part of film photography, these questions will only appeal to a very small minority of the users here. Does that make the questions too local?

Answer (score 12):

SO's mission is to provide "the long tail answers". This is the long tail of photography. I'd vote for on-topic.

Answer (score 6):

Selenium toning of negatives is even in the long tail of film photography, but I'd still call it on-topic in the sense that Karel mentions.  I'd add that such questions are pretty easy to avoid using 'ignored' tags (like I ignore 'hdr').

In the vast majority of situations, there is no appreciable distinction between digital and film photography - it's just photography.  Many people shoot film and digital, and lots of digital users may get interested in film for any number of reasons.

That said, I know a lot of film users wouldn't bother with a community that was *a priori* hostile to film content (and I've said so elsewhere on here).  It would be silly to put up such a barrier to their participation.

Comment: I thought I would put in a word for the 'digital getting interested in film' party. I am currently a digital user, and I probably will be for another year or so. However, I am very interested in large-format film, and I welcome all the knowledge that is added to this site in the form of these "long tail" questions about film development techniques. Gives me wikifacts for when I go wikidiving. ;P

Comment: Sounds good to me, it's nice to see support for obscure stuff, I just wanted to make sure that we thought about how we handle strange stuff like this.

Comment: @jrista - I was once interested in large format too. So I tried my grandfather's 6x9 Moscow 5 and the experience was interesting enough to keep me shooting film. But what I decided was that I need to first learn the emulsions and the cheapest way to learn was to buy an EF film Canon, which takes all the lenses I already have. I'm quite happy with that decision and I don't feel somehow format-limited right now, although I intend to try a true view camera at some point.

Comment: @Karel: Thanks for the advice! Good point about being able to use my existing lenses on a Canon EF film body. I'll have to look into that, as it would be a cheap way to break into film and film development.